# One vs many return values on dynamic method calls?

Tags: python, dynamic, methods, call

I'm accessing methods by name using a string :

```
def blah(str) :
  method = getattr(self,str)
  x1, x2 = method()
```

the problem is sometimes the method I'm using returns one argument instead of two and I get the following error :

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

what is the cleanest way to handle single vs. multiple return values.
thanks

Comment: What about using a list, e.g. `a_list =  method()`?

Comment: I thought about that too, but this means I have to add processing to handle one vs many case in the blah() method.

Comment: Whats wrong with that?

Comment: I expected there would be simple way :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
result = method()
try:
    x1, x2 = list(result)
except TypeError:  # "result" is not iterable
    x1, x2 = [result, None]
```

In Python, it's [easier to ask forgiveness then permission](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Note that this doesn't cover cases where `method` returns a list with wrong number of elements (i.e. not two).

For those cases, something like this might be appropriate:

```
result = method()
try:
    result_list = list(result)
except TypeError:  # "result" is not iterable
    result_list = [result]

NUMBER_OF_VARS = 2
final_list = [None] * NUMBER_OF_VARS
final_list[:min(NUMBER_OF_VARS, len(result_list))] = result_list[:NUMBER_OF_VARS]
x1, x2 = final_list
```